# Némó fíliam acerbam cónsulis ipsíus diú díligere potuit

Tags: translation-check, translation-explanation, wheelocks-latin

In the 8. practice and review exercise of the page 86 of Wheelock's Latin steht:

> Némó fíliam acerbam cónsulis ipsíus diú díligere potuit

My attempt to translate to my native Spanish goes

> Nadie ha podido apreciar a la hija cruel del mismísimo consul por mucho tiempo.

Translating it to English:

> Nobody had been able to appreciate the cruel daughter of the consul himself.

I am not sure about the meaning of *cónsulis ipsíus*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your translation is correct**. *Consulis ipsius* means exactly what you translated it to, both in Spanish (*del mismísimo cónsul*) and English (*of the consul himself*). As for the meaning of the whole sentence, I can't think of any reasonable alternative to your translation.
[Meaning of *ipse* (gen. *ipsius*)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ipse#Latin)

Comment: My worries was in it being a nested genitive.